# mysql - can I select values from the same column and show them in 2 columns result?

Tags: mysql, sql

suppose I have a table of an account entries moves, Like

```
ACCOUNTS table
+-------+------+---------+
| title | side | balance |
+-------+------+---------+
| cash  | debit|  500.0  |
+-------+------+---------+
| cash  |credit|  300.0  |
+-------+------+---------+
| cash  |credit|  600.0  |
+-------+------+---------+
#..... more than 10'000 debit and credit rows
```

I want to group the sum of credit rows and the sum of debit rows and show every sum of them in different column.

what I tried to do is to sum the balance on groups of sides , like

```
select title, side, sum(balance) from accounts group by side
```

I get **2** rows , one for debits sum, and another for credit sum, like

```
+-------+------+---------+
| cash  | debit|  500.0  |
+-------+------+---------+
| cash  |credit|  900.0  |
+-------+------+---------+
```

---

**What I want is** to get the whole result in ONE result row, the sum of debits in one field and the sum of credits in another field. I want the end result to be something like this

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| cash  | 500.0 | 900.0 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

*Thanks.*

Comment: select the sum of credit and join it to sum of debit or vica versa?

Comment: @Jacobr365 thanks. that is what I think of first , but I couldn't do it. can you give me a simple example of joining the same table!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use case

```
select title, sum( case side when 'debit' then balance else 0 end ), 
   sum( case side when 'credit' then balance else 0 end )
from accounts 
group by title
```

Comment: looks like you left an 'inner join' in there.

Comment: thanks, that is what I was looking for. I can't find this statement in SQL w3 schools . is `case` statement a SQL or it is only for mysql ?

Comment: @theaccountant . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92   is a standard  since SQL-92

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using subqueries. A lot more verbose than the CASE statement already provided but if you end up having more than one title or want to do calculations it makes it pretty straightforward.

```
SELECT
    title
    ,credit.credit_balance
    ,debit.debit_balance
    ,(credit.credit_balance - debit.debit_balance) AS net
FROM 
    (SELECT
        title,
        sum(balance) debit_balance
    FROM accounts
    WHERE 
        side = 'debit'
    GROUP BY side) debit
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        title,
        sum(balance) debit_balance
    FROM accounts
    WHERE
        side = 'credit'
    GROUP BY side) credit ON debit.title = credit.title
GROUP BY
    title;
```

Comment: thank for your time , l never tried subqueries but I will try them